# Calculation of height between header and footer

Tags: javascript, css

I created a sidenav push. I wrote a javascript function to calculate the remaining height between my header and footer as well:

```
function resizeWindow(){
  var headerHeight = $("#header-web").height();
  var footerHeight = $("#web-footer").height();
  var windowHeight = $("html").height();
  var remainHeight = windowHeight-headerHeight-footerHeight;
  $("#mySidenav").css({"height":remainHeight});
}
```

I then call it inside the one which is responsible of opening the sidenav:

```
function openNav() {
  resizeWindow();
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "400px";
  document.getElementById("map").style.marginRight = "250px";
}
```

I'm working on a mac and when the window is fully open, the sidenav occupies its adequate position, yet when it's reduced or I try to open it on another computer the div is not well placed between the header and footer.

The following capture shows the issue :

[image]

If you have an idea about what could be the source of the problem I would be grateful to learn from you!

Comment: use window.on resize event to recalculate the new size and apply it

Comment: you can do this with pure css - no need for js

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did it this way : $(window).on('resize',resizeWindow); But nothing changes.

Comment: How do you define `top` value for sidebar container?

Comment: I gave it : top: 8.5 %

Comment: issue solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for javascript at all, you could handle this with pure css

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper > header {
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:30px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.wrapper > main {
  position:relative;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > main > .scroller {
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:30px;
}

.wrapper > main > aside {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 320px;
  color:#eee;
  background:#000;
  padding:30px;
}

.wrapper > footer {
  background:#f5f5f5;
  padding:30px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="scroller">
      main content
    </div>
    <aside>
      sidebar
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>
    footer<br>brrrr<br>brrrrrrrrr
  </footer>
</div>
```